# How to check if a string only contains letters, numbers, underscores and period. Flutter/Dart

Tags: regex, string, flutter, dart

I want to check if a string **only** contains:

1. Letters
2. Numbers
3. Underscores
4. Periods

in Flutter, I tried the following to get only the letters but even if other characters are there it returns true if it contains a letter:

```
String mainString = "abc123";

print(mainString.contains(new RegExp(r'[a-z]')));
```

As I told it returns `true` since it contains letters, but I want to know if it only contains letters.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem with your `RegExp` is that you allow it to match substrings, and you match only a single character.  You can force it to require that the entire string be matched with `^` and `$`, and you can match against one or more of the expression with `+`:

```dart
print(RegExp(r'^[a-z]+$').hasMatch(mainString));
```

To match all the characters you mentioned:

```dart
print(RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+$').hasMatch(mainString));
```

Answer (score 2):

the basic way of doing this is as follow:

1. define a list of acceptable characters:

```
// for example
List<String> validChar = ["1", "2", "3", "t"];
```

2. loop through all character of your string and check its validity:

```
  // given text
  String x = "t5";
  
  bool valid = true;
  for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    if(!validChar.contains(x[i])){
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  print(valid);
```

just change the `x` and `validChar` as your need.

Comment: Currently this is O(n^2), you can make it O(n) by replacing inner validChar List with HashSet. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-collection/HashSet-class.html